MyBatis fails on one-to-many relationship with TooManyResultsException: Expected one result ... but found: 2
I have two classes which are, for now very simple:
class Club {

  private int id;
  private String name;
  private Set<Player> players;

}

class Player {

  private int id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

}

As you can see, each club can have a collection of players - a one-to-many relationship.
The XML in the mapper is as follows:
<mapper namespace="uk.co.redfruit.gdx.velvetbelly.core.data.mappers.ClubMapper" >
  <select id="getClubByName" resultType="Club" >
    select c.id as id, c.name as name,players.id as players_id, players.firstName as firstName, players.lastName as lastName from clubs c inner join players on c.id = players.club where c.name = #{name}
  </select>
  <resultMap id="Club" type="Club" >
    <result property="id" column="id" />
    <collection property="players" ofType="Player" >
      <result property="id" column="players_id" />
    </collection>
  </resultMap>
</mapper>

The code used to make the call is:
Set<Player> players = mapper.getPlayersByClubName("Testers United");
The mapper is simply an interface with the implementation obtained with session.getMapper(ClubMapper.class)
This results in the following error:

org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.TooManyResultsException: Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 2

Apart from the players_id, all the column names match the variable names in the classes. I must admit that I thought I could get away with simpler mapping as a result of this, but I can't get it working either way.
I found One to many relationship in MyBatis and also this one: MyBatis TooManyResultsException for seemingly correct mapping
and as far as I can understand it I'm not making the same mistakes as in those cases - I seem to be making all new ones...
Please don't give an answer using annotations - I'm definitely using XML in my application.
Thanks in advance!

I need to change the resultType on the select element to resultMap. Surprisingly, I also needed to map all the variables explicitly, even though the columns and variable names are all the same.

When a result map contains <collection> or <association>, auto-mapping is disabled by default. Adding autoMapping="true" to the <resultMap> might help.

Thanks for the tip - unfortunately it didn't make a difference :-(

Actually - it turns out it does work if I specifically map only the id values - everything else can then automap. Thanks again!
